# Springboot Tomcat failfast if number of connections and threads exceeded

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, microservices, tomcat8

I would like to tune Tomcat to fail-fast in case if number of threads & connections exceeded . i dont want to keep any request in queue once all connections are established and threads are processing the request.
means i want to keep server.tomcat.accept-count=0 but its not working. Is there any way to give response connection refused once server.tomcat.max-connections=5 exceed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this is not a good question for this site, it might be appropriate over on Serverfault instead of here. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: All connections pass through the queue before being assigned a working thread. A nonpositive setting for `server.tomcat.accept-count` makes no sense and is ignored by Tomcat. The minimum is **1**.

Answer (score 1):

The accept count ultimately maps down onto the `backlog` parameter of a call to [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html#bind-java.net.SocketAddress-int-). There, a value of `0` means that an implementation-specific detail is used. For this reason Tomcat ignores an attempt to set the accept count to 0, leaving its default of 100 in place.

Given that the backlog cannot be set to 0, I would configure Tomcat with an accept count of 1 instead. I believe this is as close as you can get to the behavior that you would like.